adb can't remount - Magisk on an Android 14 Samsung device
It took me a long time to finally find a way to use adb root with Magisk installed on my rooted Android 14 Samsung device, I am now able to run adb root and adb shell, therefore I can also run su commands via adb shell. However, I can't use adb remount.
I of course first ran adb root to which adb restarted successfully as root, enabling me to use the adb shell su command for example.
However, when I use the adb remount command, I get the error message /system/bin/sh: remount: inaccessible or not found.
Then I tried the common workaround of using mount -o rw,remount /. This resulted in the error '/dev/block/dm-7' is read-only.
I also tried mount -o remount,rw /system which gave me the error message mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts.
Another common workaround I tried was running adb disable-verity first, which also didn't execute properly and instead gave me: /system/bin/sh: disable-verity: inaccessible or not found.
I have the most recent Samsung adb drivers/Samsung USB drivers installed on my Windows 10 computer and also tried uninstalling Magisk, which didn't change anything at all, either.

Self-related: Can't mount anything on a rooted android device: not in /proc/mounts
